# Min max edge weight tree

Tags: python, algorithm, tree

Given a tree with N nodes and N-1 bidirectional edges, and given an integer S. Now, you have to assign the weights to the edges of this tree such that:

1.the sum of the weights of all the edges is equal to S

2.for every possible diameter of the tree, the maximum weight over all the edges covered by its path is the minimum possible.

Output the minimum possible possible weight.

Comment: There's no **question** here. You've simply dumped your homework problem without showing any effort to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to find out if there is an edge not on a diameter. If there is one, then assign all the weight to this edge and so the maximum weight on a diameter is 0. Otherwise, distribute weight evenly between edges.

One way you can do this is to find center of any diameter. Every other diameter will also go through this center. In easy case, diameter has even number of edges, you need to run DFS form the center point and check if distances to all the leaves are the same. If yes, then return `S/#edges`, otherwise return `0`. In case diameter has odd number of edges, you can add virtual vertex in the middle of central edge of the diameter and start from it. The complexity is `O(V+E)`.

Answer (score 2):

The approach is correct, but the algorithm is not.

Example : 1 - 2 , 1 - 3, 1 - 4, 4 - 5 , 
2 is the endpoint of one of the diameters
but (2 - 3) distance is not the same as (2, 5)

But in this tree, each edge is the part of the diameter.

Comment: Thanks for the test case, i tried to simplify the algorithm, but it apparently doesn't work this way, so i restored original version.

Comment: Yes, we can check for each edge whether that edge is a  part of any diameter or not, in O(n) complexity.  For each edge (u - v), find the maximum distance from u to any node away from v let say D1, and same for node v away from u,  let say D2, then that edge will contribute  (D1 + D2 + 1),   with Dp we can calculate this information for each edge.